# Terraform | Replacing multiple substrings in a string

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a string and there are multiple substrings that will need to be replaced in it.

The string:
`string1 = "I want to fly tomorrow"`

I will need to take whatever that needs to replaced from a map.

The map:

```
map1 = {
    "I": "we"
    "want": "do not want"
    "tomorrow": "today"
  }
```

So the keys in the `map1` map are what need to be replaced in the `string1` string and the values should be the new values in the string.

The result should look something like this:
`we do not want to fly today`

I have been thinking of a solution but I am not even close.

I tried this:

```
try = [for replacement in keys(local.map1): replace(local.string1, replacement, local.map1[replacement])]
```

but this returns a list of strings that each have only one value replaced.

***NOTE***: `string1` and `map1` are just examples and they could have any other values so I am looking for a general solution please :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is something that was needed for work; this was tested on Terraform 0.12.23. Different from Marcin's answer in the sense that this works for placeholders that are right next to each other, in between characters (such as quotes), or otherwise not split by spaces.

Given we have a file with `{}` formatted placeholders, I needed to replace them with a map of key/value pairs.

Here's what you can copy/paste.

**sample.txt**

```
Hello {name}, my favorite food is {food} I'd
  like to eat {food} and sleep.
  Here's a {non_existent} variable
```

**playground.tf**

```
locals {
  input = file("./sample.txt")

  map = {
    food = "Sushi"
    name = "Data_sniffer"
  }

  out = join("\n", [
    for line in split("\n", local.input) :
      format(
        replace(line, "/{(${join("|", keys(local.map))})}/", "%s"),
        [
          for value in flatten(regexall("{(${join("|", keys(local.map))})}", line)) :
            lookup(local.map, value)
        ]...
      )
  ])
}

output "test_out" {
  value = local.out
}
```

**Output**

```
$ terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

test_out = Hello Data_sniffer, my favorite food is Sushi I'd
  like to eat Sushi and sleep.
  Here's a {non_existent} variable
```

---

Here's an explanation of how this magic works:

1. The first step is to split up your text by newlines, so you'll have the following to work with:

   ```json
   [
     "Hello {name}, my favorite food is {food} I'd",
     "  like to eat {food} and sleep.",
     "  Here's a {non_existent} variable"
   ]
   ```
2. Now we want to replace our placeholders. However, at the time of writing this, Terraform doesn't have an easy way to replace multiple string easily in one string. So we'll use the [`format`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/format.html) function in the meantime; which requires `%s` for its placeholders. Basically, we want our array to now look like this:

   ```json
   [
     "Hello %s, my favorite food is %s I'd",
     "  like to eat %s and sleep.",
     "  Here's a {non_existent} variable"
   ]
   ```

   In order to get this conversion for each line, we want to replace our valid `{}` placeholders with `%s`; i.e. we don't want to replace `{non_existent}` which doesn't exist in our map.

   We take advantage of the fact that Terraform allows you to do regex replacements, so we need the following regex: `{(food|name)}` (where `food` and `name` are the keys that we want to replace). Since we don't want to manually maintain this list, we build the regular expression programmatically with [`keys()`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/keys.html) and [string interpolation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/strings.html#interpolation).

   ```
   "/{(${join("|", keys(local.map))})}/"
   ```

   Now that we have a regex, we can use [`replace`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/replace.html), which supports regular expressions.

   ```
   replace(line, "/{(${join("|", keys(local.map))})}/", "%s")
   ```
3. But wait! All we have now are `%s`, how are we going to know what to replace in what order??? That's where [`regexall()`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/regexall.html) comes in (**not** `regex()`). Using *almost* the same regex above, we'll pull out the matching placeholders once again.

   (The only difference between the regex above and this one is the lack of `/` at the beginning and ending)

   ```
   regexall("{(${join("|", keys(local.map))})}", "Hello {name}, my favorite food is {food} I'd")
   ```

   This function call will return all of our found placeholders. It's important to use `regexall()` all here or else it'll stop at the first match.

   ```json
   [
     [
       "name"
     ],
     [
       "food"
     ]
   ]
   ```

   We don't need the doubly nested lists here, so we'll use [`flatten()`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/flatten.html).

   ```
   flatten(
     regexall("{(${join("|", keys(local.map))})}", "Hello {name}, my favorite food is {food} I'd")
   )
   ```

   Which now will return,

   ```json
   [
     "name",
     "food",
   ]
   ```

   Now, we can use *this* list to lookup what the respective values would be from the map with the [`lookup()`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/lookup.html) function.

   ```
   [
     for value in flatten(regexall("{(${join("|", keys(local.map))})}", "Hello {name}, my favorite food is {food} I'd")) :
       lookup(local.map, value)
   ]
   ```

   Which returns:

   ```
   [
     "Data_sniffer",
     "Sushi",
   ]
   ```

   This array of replacement values can then be fed into our top-level `format()` call. However, `format()` doesn't accept an array it expects comma-separated arguments. So use the [`...` operator](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/function-calls.html#expanding-function-arguments) to expand the list into function arguments.

Comment: One thing - this will fail if your source string contains % characters, such as the kubernetes yaml manifest I am working on - just replace any existing %s with something like \\§\\ and switch them back after the replacement. Otherwise absolutely spot on, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I think you do this is as follows:

```
variable "string1" {
  default = "I want to fly tomorrow"
}

variable "map1" {
  default = {
    "I" = "we"
    "want" = "do not want"
    "tomorrow" = "today"
  }
}

output "test" {
  value = join(" ", [for word in split(" ", var.string1): lookup(var.map1, word, word)]) 
}
```

output is:

```
we do not want to fly today
```

Comment: Clever algorithm for iterating on strings and for using `lookup` to replace or default to original element as desired.

Comment: Kudos to you @marcin

Comment: Am I missing something? Why isn't this answer getting the most votes? This algorithm is much simpler and easier to understand than the other answer.